# Fabric - possible to have local and remote task execution in one method?

Tags: python, fabric

Is it possible to have local and remote tasks execute from within the same task method?

e.g., I want to do something like the following:

```
@fabric.api.task
def Deploy():
    PrepareDeploy()
    PushDeploy()
    execute(Extract())
    execute(Start())
```

Where `PrepareDeploy` and `PushDeploy` are local tasks (executing only locally, via the `fabric.api.local()` method):

```
@fabric.api.task
@fabric.decorators.runs_once
def PrepareDeploy():

@fabric.api.task
@fabric.decorators.runs_once
def PushDeploy():
```

And `Extract`/`Start` are methods that should be run on the remote hosts themselves:

```
@fabric.api.task
def Extract():

@fabric.api.task
def Start():
```

However, when I try to do `fab Deploy`, I get something like:

```
[remote1.serv.com] Executing task 'Deploy'
[localhost] local: find . -name "*.java" > sources.txt
 ...
```

The first line seems wrong to me (and in fact, causes errors).

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn new task and defining on what hosts should it run, for example - how to create rabbitmq of all hosts are provisioned with puppet with the same erlang cookie.

See around line 114 - there is an executon of the tasks on specific hosts.

https://gist.github.com/nvtkaszpir/17d2e2180771abd93c46

I hope this helps.